# Using super() with a single argument in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, super

I read quite a lot of material about the correct use of `super` with and without argument(s) but there is still something that I do not understand.

Let's consider the following example:

```
class A:
    def foo(self):
        pass

class B(A):
    pass
```

This is the part I understand:

```
super(B, B())  # <bound method A.foo of <__main__.B object at ...>>
```

which makes sense, as the two argument version of `super`, with the second argument being an object returns a bound object.

Let's say that I want to access the function in `A`, not the bound method. I would try this:

```
super(B).foo  # AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'foo'
```

Which is the part that I do not understand.

Trying to "trick" `super` in the following way works though:

```
super(B, B).foo  # <function __main__.A.foo(self)>
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

`super` returns a proxy to *some* object. To figure out which object you want to proxy, you need to see how you would get a reference to the function without using `super`.

If `a` is an instance of `A`, then `a.foo` gives you the return value of `A.__dict__['foo'].__get__(a, A)`, which is an instance of `method`. To get the function itself, you use `A.foo`, which is the return value of `A.__dict__['foo'].__get__(None, A)`.

This suggests you need a proxy for the *class*, not the instance of the class, which is why you pass `A`, rather than an instance of `A`, as the second argument to `super`.

Comment: I get what you mean about the "translation" from the "dot" operator to the call to `__get__` in the dict, however, I don't see why in the end it behaves like it does.

Comment: OK, I think I get it: the single argument form provides a non-bound (super) proxy object, not a non-bound function or whatever. So in this case: `B._super = super(B);
B()._super.foo` it again works as for `super(B, b)` and thus returns a bound method. And a function when doing `super(B, B)` as you described.